# Maven Dependency for Oracle RDS on AWS

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jdbc, java-8

I'm having trouble connecting to my AWS Oracle RDS instance, I have a connection in SQL developer all cool and fine.

Upon loading my application context (spring boot | java 8)>

```
*org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: 
........................................................................................................................................................
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [jdbc:oracle:thin:@########:1521/DBNAME]*
```

would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me in the correct direction as to what artifactid groupid and version I should use. Current is below and wrong:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Full Stack Trace:

2018-07-06 07:03:15.670 ERROR 88631 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6e2375e]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaDBDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'jpaDBDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [jdbc:oracle:thin:@****************************************]

Comment: Please add the full stack trace. Is there a `NoClassDefFoundError` down the stack trace?

Comment: Full Stack trace. Also thanks so much for your time!!

Comment: By the looks of it, you have specified the URL in the config property for the driver class name. Fix your config.